# How to make this div always align center?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the div class ty-product-block__wrapper align in the center (**Horizontally**) for all devices. The image used is for illustrative purposes only. I have been trying to figure it out for a while and I can't get it to work. Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6txxshk9/

HTML

```
<div class="ty-tygh">
<div class="ty-helper-container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span16">
      <div class="ty-product-block">
        <div lcass="ty-product-block__wrapper">
          <img src="http://blogsbucket.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-dk-flat.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {display: block;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0;
}
.ty-tygh {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ty-helper-container {
  position: relative;
}
.row-fluid {
  width: 100%;
}
.row-fluid .span16 {
  width: 100%;
}
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.ty-product-block {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.ty-product-block__wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: maybe simply: https://jsfiddle.net/6txxshk9/10/ (display:table turns it into a block element shrinking/expanding according to its content. margin:auto; centers it if less than 100% width :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks, that worked well :D

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

**Horizontal Centering**

```
.ty-product-block {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Vertical Centering**

```
.ty-product-block {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6txxshk9/3/**

Comment: I can't do that because div is used in a lot of other areas of the website. The only 2 that can be edited are :
<div class="ty-product-block">
        <div lcass="ty-product-block__wrapper">

Comment: @Grant9196 Updated. Check, you didn't say this before.

Comment: I don't think it has been updated

Comment: @PraveenKumar look, your speed is unbelievable ..!

Comment: @Grant9196 Refresh. I have changed `div` to classnames: `.ty-product-block`

Comment: @Shafizadeh Ha ha ha... `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Can you send the link please. Thanks :P

Comment: @Grant9196 What link?

Comment: Where have you changed div to .ty-product-block?

Comment: @Grant9196 refresh your page and see the above answer...

Comment: @Grant9196 I haven't updated the fiddle

Comment: Oh right, I see. If you try that in fiddle, I don;'t think it works